# How to Specify Tablespace for XML Type Index creation in Oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, oracle-xml-db

I am trying to create an XML Index on XML Type column in one of my table. 
We are using 2 tablespace here, one for Tables and the second for Indexes.

I would like to create the XMLIndex in the index tablespace.

I am using the below query -

```
CREATE INDEX VISION_IX1 ON MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL(RAWMESSAGE)
INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLINDEX
NOPARALLEL;
```

Please help me with where to mention the tablespace clause.

Comment: Do you mean [like this example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_indexing.htm#BCGDDBDI)?

Comment: I actually saw this example. but, in this we are specifying particular path for which we will create the index. 
The SQL query i mentioned above will create an index on overall XML type column. I need to know where to add the table space clause in that

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the path table to be able to specify the storage [for the unstructured component](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_indexing.htm#BCGEJHBG):

```
CREATE TABLE MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL(ID NUMBER, RAWMESSAGE XMLTYPE) TABLESPACE TS_TABLES;

Table MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL created.

CREATE INDEX VISION_IX1 ON MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL(RAWMESSAGE)
INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLINDEX
PARAMETERS('PATH TABLE VISION_IX_PATH_TABLE (TABLESPACE TS_INDEXES)')
NOPARALLEL;

Index VISION_IX1 created.
```

You can see where the storage has been allocated:

```
SELECT US.SEGMENT_NAME, US.SEGMENT_TYPE, US.TABLESPACE_NAME
FROM USER_OBJECTS UO
JOIN USER_SEGMENTS US
ON US.SEGMENT_NAME = UO.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE UO.CREATED > TRUNC(SYSDATE);

SEGMENT_NAME                   SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME              
------------------------------ ------------------ ------------------------------
MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL         TABLE              TS_TABLES                         
SYS304166_VISION_IX_PIKEY_IX   INDEX              TS_TABLES                         
SYS304166_VISION_IX_VALUE_IX   INDEX              TS_TABLES                         
SYS_IL0000304163C00003$$       LOBINDEX           TS_TABLES                         
SYS_LOB0000304163C00003$$      LOBSEGMENT         TS_TABLES                         
VISION_IX_PATH_TABLE           TABLE              TS_INDEXES
```

You can specify that the other two indexes that creates go in your preferred tablespace too:

```
CREATE INDEX VISION_IX1 ON MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL(RAWMESSAGE)
INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLINDEX
PARAMETERS('PATH TABLE VISION_IX_PATH_TABLE (TABLESPACE TS_TABLES)
  PIKEY INDEX VISION_IX_PIKEY (TABLESPACE TS_INDEXES)
  VALUE INDEX VISION_IX_VALUE (TABLESPACE TS_INDEXES)')
NOPARALLEL;

SELECT US.SEGMENT_NAME, US.SEGMENT_TYPE, US.TABLESPACE_NAME
FROM USER_OBJECTS UO
JOIN USER_SEGMENTS US
ON US.SEGMENT_NAME = UO.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE UO.CREATED > TRUNC(SYSDATE);

SEGMENT_NAME                   SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME              
------------------------------ ------------------ ------------------------------
MDT_VISION_LOGGING_TBL         TABLE              TS_TABLES                         
SYS_IL0000304183C00003$$       LOBINDEX           TS_TABLES                         
SYS_LOB0000304183C00003$$      LOBSEGMENT         TS_TABLES                         
VISION_IX_PATH_TABLE           TABLE              TS_INDEXES                        
VISION_IX_PIKEY                INDEX              TS_INDEXES                        
VISION_IX_VALUE                INDEX              TS_INDEXES
```